# Issue Undefined variable after storing mysql query into a php variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an issue on my php script. I am trying to store mysql query into a php variable and then I convert the result to string. It seems doing the job in the loop but at the end of my script, I have an error:

Internal Error -

> Notice:Undefined variable: result

I want to pass the whole content of the variable $data.
Do you know what i am doing wrong?

**Here my php script**:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data']) {
$SelectDataFromRunTable="Select Reference, Variant, HGVSVar FROM run29012016";
$QueryResult=mysqli_query($conn,$SelectDataFromRunTable);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryResult,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
print_r($data);
$data=implode(" ",$data);
}//end of while
$NameChecker='astringtest';
$options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    $client = new SoapClient($URL, $options);
try {
   $result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data'=>$data, 'process'=>$NameChecker))
                  ->submitBatchJobResult;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


print_r($result);

mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Its always better to define you variable first instead of using them directly simply declare `$result` before `try{}catch` and check your code as its not getting an `data` within `$result`

Comment: or may be $result = $e->getMessage(); in exception.

Comment: or set $result = array(); in default at top level declaration.

Comment: or you can also check it by using isset()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryResult,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
>   $data = implode(" ",$data);
> }
> ```

This can not work, as you overriding $data with every loop:

`while($data = mysqli_fetch_array(...))` will evaluate as many times you have rows in your dataset, till the end. The last assignmet is `$data = null` (e.g. when you reached the end of you result set) and you are going out of the while-loop.

What you can do is, store you data into another variable, like

```
$soap_data = "";
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryResult,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
  $soap_data .= " " . implode(" ",$data);
}

//...

$result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data'=>$soap_data, 'process'=>$NameChecker))
                  ->submitBatchJobResult;
```

Also, what devpro said, it is always better to include a default for variables.

Comment: thx for your help. I did the modification. But, if I do an echo of $soap_data after while loop, I have only the last element into and not the whole content.`$soap_data = "";
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryResult,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
  $soap_data=implode(" ",$data);
}
echo $soap_data;`

Comment: Forgott the concat to the old result. No it should work.

Comment: Is there any solution to get the whole content stored into a variable after the while loop?

Comment: in the WSDL description, they say data as Binary64

Comment: Binary64 could be anything. To format it correctly, you have to know, how the data should be formatted...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `$result` in default at top level like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data']) 
{
    $result = array(); // ADD THIS
    $SelectDataFromRunTable="Select Reference, Variant, HGVSVar FROM run29012016";
    $QueryResult=mysqli_query($conn,$SelectDataFromRunTable);
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryResult,MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
        print_r($data);
        $data=implode(" ",$data);
    }//end of while
    $NameChecker='astringtest';
    $options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    $client = new SoapClient($URL, $options);
    try 
    {
       $result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data'=>$data, 'process'=>$NameChecker))
                      ->submitBatchJobResult;

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    print_r($result);

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**What i have changed?**

I am adding `$result = array();` in default.

Comment: I did the modication as you adviced to me but, I have now this error:`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap11env:Server] Internal Error in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/test/submitbatchjob2.php:42 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/test/submitbatchjob2.php(42): SoapClient->__call('submitBatchJob', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ngs/test/submitbatchjob2.php on line 42`. I think, the issue, is the $data is empty after the loop while. How can I solve that?

Comment: @user979974: this will resolve your undefined notice issue, for second issue, u can check other answer (fabian-)

Comment: yeah thx, I applied fabian solution and it has removed undefined notice issue. But I wanted to know if there is any solution to get the whole content stored into a variable after the while loop?

Comment: @user979974: good to know, your issue has resolved, dont forget to appreciate .... now yes u can use output buffering.. maybe it will help u. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `$result` outside where this var was defined.

try this:

```
try {

  $result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data'=>$data,    'process'=>$NameChecker))
              ->submitBatchJobResult;
  print_r($result);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```